# qloginやqsubを実行する際にエラーが起こり、ジョブを投げられない

Tags: matlab

qloginやqsubを実行する際にエラーが起こりジョブを投げられず，困っています．
また，条件は不明ですが，どちらの場合もまれに成功する場合もあります．

qloginコマンドを実行した結果で失敗の場合

```
[aiueo@hostname sim]$ qlogin
Your job 865534 ("QLOGIN") has been submitted
waiting for interactive job to be scheduled ...timeout (5 s) expired while waiting on socket fd 4

Could not start interactive job.
```

qstatの結果

```
[aiueo@hostname sim]$ qstat -j 865565
==============================================================
job_number:                 865565
jclass:                     NONE
exec_file:                  job_scripts/865565
submission_time:            Thu Aug 17 11:52:26 2017
owner:                      aiueo
uid:                        3021
group:                      nca
gid:                        3000
sge_o_home:                 /home/aiueo
sge_o_log_name:             aiueo
sge_o_path:                 /opt/uge/bin/lx-amd64:/home/aiueo/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/home/aiueo/bin
sge_o_shell:                /bin/bash
sge_o_workdir:              /home/aiueo/Documents/underconnectivity/WT/sim/0_002/1
sge_o_host:                 prince
account:                    sge
cwd:                        /home/aiueo/Documents/underconnectivity/WT/sim/0_002/1
mail_list:                  aiueo@hostname.local
notify:                     FALSE
job_name:                   v-0_002|t-1
jobshare:                   0
hard_queue_list:            long.q
shell_list:                 NONE:/bin/bash
env_list:                   
script_file:                runCluster.sh
binding:                    NONE
mbind:                      NONE
error reason    1:          can't get password entry for user "aiueo". Either the user does not exist or NIS error!
```

#### 追記

環境情報です。

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)
$ ypcat passwd | grep aiueo
aiueo:$1$omH7y8kL$DVBof4qaF94JmEZaXcOxP0:3021:3000::/data03/‌​home/aiueo:/bin/bash
```

追加情報です
たまに成功することがあり、成功時のメッセージは以下です

Your job 865535 ("QLOGIN") has been submitted waiting for interactive job to be scheduled ... Your interactive job 865535 has been successfully scheduled. Establishing /opt/uge/default/common/qlogin.sh session to host node27.local .

$ qacct -j 865565 | grep hostname
hostname     node20.local

Comment: Grid engine の計算ノード(ジョブが実行されるホスト)の中に、NIS のクライントとして設定されていないホストがあるのかもしれません。例えば上記のジョブで言うと `qacct -j 865565 | grep hostname`  の実行結果からジョブが実行されようとしたホストが分かりますので、そのホストで NIS の設定が適切に行われているのかどうかを確認してみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: $ qacct -j 865565 | grep hostname
hostname     node20.local

Answer (score 1):

qstat実行結果の最後に"aiueo"ユーザーのパスワードエントリが見つからない(またはNISのエラー)と出ています。

もし実行元と実行先とが異なるホストの場合は、実行先にも"aiueo"ユーザーが存在するかを確認してみてください。

**追記**
実行のたびに成功・失敗のケースが出てくるのはジョブの投入先が複数あり、そのうちいくつかのホストでアカウント情報(aiueo)が正しく引き継ぎできないのが原因だと思います。

・まずは失敗した場合のジョブ情報(qstat,qacct等)から、どのホストで問題が起きるのかを絞り込んでください。
・ホストが絞り込めたら、問題のホストに**ジョブの投入元と同じアカウント**(aiueo)でログインできるかを確認してください。例えばsshログインができるか等。
・もしログイン出来ない場合には問題のホスト上に「アカウント情報を追加する」「NISの登録を行う」か、もしくはシステムの管理者に問い合わせてみてください。

---

「ジョブの投入元」「投入先」で最低でも2台、投入先によって「成功する」「失敗する」で計3台以上のホストがあるはずなのでまずはそれらをリストアップ、それぞれのホスト上で`ypcat passwd | grep aiueo`で結果がどう表示されるかを確認してみてください。

Comment: たまに成功することがあり、成功時のメッセージは以下です。

Comment: Your job 865535 ("QLOGIN") has been submitted
waiting for interactive job to be scheduled ...
Your interactive job 865535 has been successfully scheduled.
Establishing /opt/uge/default/common/qlogin.sh session to host node27.local ...

Comment: ジョブの投入先にはrshでログインできるように設定してあるんですが、成功している投入先はrshでログインできますが、失敗している投入先にはrshでログインできませんでした。アカウント情報が正しく引き継げてないようです。